# Is there a Perl Syntax Highlighter (outputting to HTML) like PHP's GeSHi?

Tags: perl, syntax-highlighting

Most PHP Developers are likely familar with the Syntax Highlighter called "[GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)", which takes code, highlights it, with the use of HTML and CSS:

```
include('geshi.php');
$source = 'echo "hello, world!";
$language = 'php';
$path = 'geshi/';
$geshi = new GeSHi($source, $language, $path);
echo $geshi->parse_code();
```

GeSHi Supports a [wide range of languages](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html#features).

I wonder, is there a similar Module for Perl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Perl has a port of [Kate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_(text_editor)) highlighting system: [Syntax::Highlight::Engine::Kate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Syntax::Highlight::Engine::Kate) which seems to be somewhat close to what you need. It appears to be part of [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/).
2. You also have an option of HTML client side highlighters (logic is obviously JS), such as [Google's code prettifyer](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)
3. Two good lists of syntax highlighting engines are:

   - [Wiki syntax highlighting article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting#Syntax_highlighting_engines) - among the ones it lists, the Perl ports/APIs seem to exist for Kate and [Colorer (Syntax::Highlight::Universal)](http://search.cpan.org/~palant/Syntax-Highlight-Universal/)
   - [This very good review of HTML syntax highlighters](http://www.xibl.com/web-development/html-syntax-highlighters/), which contains a lot of client-side ones such as SHJS and many others.
4. Please be aware that NONE of those generic highlighters work "100% correctly", the way the syntax highlighters work in good IDEs, because they use regular expressions for approximate parsing instead of lexers for actual language grammar parsing. More details [on the Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting#History_and_limitations)

Comment: Syntax::Highlight::Engine::Kate looks promising, though I find it a little depressing that there are only so few serverside highlighting engines for perl...

Comment: @nebukadnezzar - Why? My guess is that Perl was not used as a back-end for a significant number of web uses which required such functionality (contrasted with phpBB for php), and whatever minor need was there was already fulfilled by client-side solutions. So there was just no demand, outside of Perl-implemented IDEs (thus, Kate was ported presumably for Padre purposes). I know if I needed such a functionality, I would definitely go for client side library first.

Comment: Yes, I guess that the demand for this kind of functionality for Perl isn't very high. But considering that GeSHi uses mainly regular expressions, I figured that writing one isn't very difficult... Also, I guess that using a client side highlighter is likely a better option for now.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar - I haven't scrutinized the GeSGi source, but based on the sample language files, it probably wouldn't be overly complicated to port should someone really need it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider this for client side syntax highlighting.
http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 1):

I have had some very good results with the [PPI::HTML](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-HTML-1.08/) package. It uses [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-1.213/) to parse the Perl before converting the text to HTML.

Comment: The biggest strength of GeSHi is the wide range of supported languages. I don't see such a thing in PPI::HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Perl: Syntax::Highlight::Engine::Kate (there is Kate plugin for Padre IDE).

Wrappers for C libraries: Syntax::Highlight::Universal, Syntax::SourceHighlight.

Using external tools: Text::VimColor, Text::EmacsColor.

Also there are many one-language highlighters on CPAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a small php script to make GeSHi usable from command line and then call it within your perl script.
I did this for gitweb so I could leave svn (and websvn) behind for good.

Answer (score 0):

My search brought me here, because I was looking for a 'Perl Syntax Highlighter' like the title said and not an general highlighter implemented in Perl.

To highlight only Perl, `perltidy --html` can be used. It belongs to the `Perl::Tidy` distribution the main module can be imported and used without spawning a process.

https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy/view/bin/perltidy#HTML-OPTIONS

So not what the OP actually wanted to know, but hopefully of help for others coming here for the same reasons like me ... :)