# Working on syntax highlighter perl

Tags: regex, perl

Just started working on the assignment (code in Perl) for syntax highlighter. I need to match comments, keywords and strings and highlight them in different colours.
Can anyone give me a hint where to start with? I've just got only two weeks for this.
I use regex to split every line of the file into tokens. For example

```
  $my string = 'my @array = (56, "string", 56.5758);';
  my @b = $string =~ /([A-Za-z0-9'"\._\@\#\$]+)/g;
```

that gives:

```
  my
  @array
  56
 'string'
  56.5758
```

then I can start analysing them. I've got the following questions:
1. How can I put back these tokens back to the string? I mean I've got spaces, parentheses, ";" and other characters that used to be between tokens. How can I do again?

```
  '<keyword>my</keyword> @array = (56, <string>"string"<string>, 56.5758);
```

2. What' the best way to write highlighter? Just using regex and try to model all different situations?

Any help guys would be much appreciated. I have not progress much so far.

Many thanks

Comment: if you can write a single regex that can handle arbitrary perl code, then you can probably complete replace larry wall and take over perl development.

Comment: I don't know what I can invent better for two weeks period

Comment: You could stop reinventing the wheel... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529975/is-there-a-perl-syntax-highlighter-outputting-to-html-like-phps-geshi

Comment: any help on Question1?

Answer (score 8):

Do not try to use regex; use [PPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI).  Any attempt to parse perl is fraught with peril; PPI has solved that problem for almost all perl code likely to be encountered.

There's still plenty of code to write to make a syntax highlighter from it; you should check if you can use it.  (And if you can't, I think poorly of your instructor for mandating such a task; much better to have made the assignment to write a syntax highlighter for a something that can be represented in BNF or EBNF such as [C](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf) or [Python](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/grammar.html) or [sudoers](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man5/sudoers.5.html).)

Comment: ysth: thanks, I'll check that. Any ideas on my Q1? Is is possible in Perl? Or I just have to do a loop through tokens and use substitution to add <tag>?

Comment: your tokens should include everything, even punctuation; then it gets much easier to reassemble into a string.